# Visual Studio 2017 some tools not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, toolbox

I am trying to create a program in Visual Studio 2017 Community version in Visual C#. After I create a Windows Form App (Windows Classic Desktop) and open the Toolbox I am missing tools such as Label, TextBox and many others. What do I miss or what did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your vs install is completed succesfully? This looks like a corrupted or interrupted install? Did you try to repair?

Comment: Yes, I reinstalled all the workloads for Windows + all the optional tools etc..

Comment: Which tools _are_ showing?

Comment: The toolbox will show controls, if you open the form in design mode. Are you sure you opened the form in design mode?

Comment: Resetting the toolbox solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with "Right Click" on Toolbox bar and "Reset Toolbox".

Answer (score 2):

Try to right click on the Toolbox and select "Reset Toolbox".

I think it must help you.

Or reinstall Visual Studio.